# How can I copy location info from geotagged phone images to images taken with my other camera around the same time?

Tags: lightroom, geotagging, android

So i did quite a big trip recently, and took lots of pictures with my DSLR and occasionally Android phone.
Only after coming back did i read about the whole GPX file, tracklog options in Lightroom.
meaning i don't have such a tracklog file.

The android phone did geotag most photos it took. (at least, when it got a gps fix i guess)

So my question is, is there some software or way that will automatically copy the geotag from the android's photos to photos taken on the same time with my DSLR?

Or alternatively, generate a tracklog from the geotagged data in the android pictures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It seems that there is no way to create a tracklog from within Lightroom. I just did a Google search on that and looked in Lightroom 4 for options.
2. You can [create a tracklog from your geotagged pictures using `exiftools`](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/geotag.html#GPX).

   Save the following print configuration to a file named `gpx.fmt` in your working directory.

   ```
   #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   # File:         gpx.fmt
   #
   # Description:  Example ExifTool print format file for generating GPX track log
   #
   # Usage:        exiftool -p gpx.fmt FILE [...] > out.gpx
   #
   # Requires:     ExifTool version 10.49 or later
   #
   # Revisions:    2010/02/05 - P. Harvey created
   #               2018/01/03 - PH Added IF to be sure position exists
   #               2018/01/06 - PH Use DateFmt function instead of -d option
   #
   # Notes:     1) Input files must contain GPSLatitude and GPSLongitude.
   #            2) Add the -ee option to extract the full track from video files.
   #            3) The -fileOrder option may be used to control the order of the
   #               generated track points when processing multiple files.
   #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   #[HEAD]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   #[HEAD]<gpx version="1.0"
   #[HEAD] creator="ExifTool $ExifToolVersion"
   #[HEAD] xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   #[HEAD] xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
   #[HEAD] xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
   #[HEAD]<trk>
   #[HEAD]<number>1</number>
   #[HEAD]<trkseg>
   #[IF]  $gpslatitude $gpslongitude
   #[BODY]<trkpt lat="$gpslatitude#" lon="$gpslongitude#">
   #[BODY]  <ele>$gpsaltitude#</ele>
   #[BODY]  <time>${gpsdatetime#;DateFmt("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")}</time>
   #[BODY]</trkpt>
   #[TAIL]</trkseg>
   #[TAIL]</trk>
   #[TAIL]</gpx>
   ```

   Run the following command. It will read all the geo information out of the exif data from the android pictures and create a XML document formatted in the GPX way.

   ```
   exiftool -fileOrder gpsdatetime -p gpx.fmt -ext jpg . > out.gpx
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an Eyefi sd card in your camera so as the card sends the files to your android device,  the Eyefi app will add the GPS info to the EXIF data. Totally automated.

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't an automated solution, if you manually select the group of photos that you took at the same location as one from Android, you can Ctrl-click (or Command-click for Mac) on the location on the map that the Android photo is at and it will place them with it and update the Geotagging.

Answer (score 1):

- `exiftool` can be used to create a `gpx` file, as [Unapiedra describes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/42669/75526). In some Linux distributions, the `gpx.fmt` is already installed. After the `gpx` file has been created, `exiftool` can be called again to tag untagged files. Change filenames and time-zones as appropriate.

  ```
  exiftool -fileOrder gpsdatetime -p /usr/share/doc/libimage-exiftool-perl/fmt_files/gpx.fmt -ext jpg . > out.gpx

  exiftool -if 'not ($GPSLatitude or $GPSLongitude)' -geotag out.gpx '-geotime<${createdate}-00:00' -r -ext jpg  .
  ```
- If you have Google Location History turned on, you can download KML files from Google [Timeline](https://www.google.com/maps/timeline) or [Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/). Then use `exiftool` to tag your photos.

  ```
  exiftool -if 'not ($GPSLatitude or $GPSLongitude)' -geotag history.kml '-geotime<${createdate}-00:00' -r -ext jpg  .
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this tool https://github.com/stxh/gpsMerge
You can use your phone photos as GPS source to sync your camera photos
The python tool easy runs on Mac and Linux. As windows user, you can donwload stand along package from its release section.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! Nice to see that you  wrote a package to do this, it seems very useful. Could you please edit your answer to include that you wrote it? It's considered good practice to reveal any involvement when suggesting software. Also, there is a lack of information on how to use this tool. I found that *after* you download the release, there is a README with more info, but that's a bit cumbersome to find. Could you perhaps expand your answer with an example on how one would use the tool?