# How to copy location info from nearby photos?

Tags: geotagging, locations

I often take pictures back and forth between my iPhone and Nikon DSLR while hiking. The iPhone stores location information. The Nikon does not.

For example, I may have photos like:

- pic1.nef @ 1:30
- img200.heic @ 1:31
- img201.heic @ 1:32
- img202.heic @ 1:39
- pic2.nef @ 1:40
- pic3.nef @ 1:41
- pic4.nef @ 1:43
- img202.heic @ 1:44

I'd like to automatically have pic1 inherit the location of img200, pic2 and pic3 take the location of img202, and pic4 take the location of img202.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Geotag photos based on android's geotagged photos](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42668/geotag-photos-based-on-androids-geotagged-photos)

Answer (score 1):

Nikon View NX-i can copy Geo-tag info to other pictures, see here:
https://nikonimglib.com/nvnxi/onlinehelp/en/nk107000.html
I don't know if it will open Iphone pictures and read their geo-tag info though, you would have to try.

If you like to have geo-tag info, I would recommend just using an app for it. I have gps4cam pro, and it works perfectly. I haven't tried, but according to some reviews I found before I chose it, it is much easier than the very expensive Nikon geo-tag device. I have read that it drains the camera's battery and takes very long to lock position. It is also quite big.

Comment: While this allows me to copy metadata, it doesn't answer the heart of the issue: copying from several photos to several other photos temporally co-located.

Answer (score 0):

I also use my iPhone for GPS locale when using an SLR that does not have built-in GPS capability.  During post processing in Lightroom, I load the iPhone pic with the SLR pics.  I then find the iPhone pic in the Map module and drag and drop the related SLR pics onto that location.  This has pretty much sufficed fo adding location info to the metadata of pics taken with a non-GPS enabled SLR.